# Flex: Label.addChild() not working?

Tags: apache-flex

I want to make a label that has a tiny title above it, for example so the label say **$1,000** with a small *retail price* or *our price* above it. I am trying to add the title label to the display list of the main label. I get no error but the title does not show up. I also considered rawChildren but apparently Label has no rawChildren property.

Here is my code:

```
package
{
    import mx.controls.Label;

    public class PriceLabel extends StrikeThroughLabel //<-- exntension of label to add strike
    {
        private var _title:Label;

        public function PriceLabel()
        {
            super();
        }

        [Bindable]
        public function set title(s:String):void
        {
            if(_title == null)
            {
                _title = new Label();
                addChild(_title);
                this.alpha = .2;
            }
            _title.text = s;
        }
        public function get title():String
        {
            var s:String
            if(_title != null)
            {
                s = _title.text;
            }
            return s;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add children to a Flex component that is not a container, then you have to manually manage sizing and positioning of those children. Containers do a lot of that work for you.

Here's what you should do:

1. Move the creation of your child Label into an override of the `createChildren()` function.
2. Set the `text` property of the child label in an override of the `commitProperties()` function. Your `title` getter and setter should save the value in a `_title` variable to be used later for the assignment in `commitProperties()`. This is actually important for performance.
3. Override the `measure()` function and update `measuredWidth` and `measuredHeight` to be the maximum width and height values of the main label and it's child.
4. Override `updateDisplayList()` and use `setActualSize()` on the child Label to set it to the required width and height.

That may seem like a lot of work, but in terms of best practices, that's the way you're supposed to build custom components. The Flex Team at Adobe spent a lot of time maximizing performance, and that's why things happen in several steps like that.

That's how to do it based on what you asked. Personally, I would make a subclass of UIComponent with two Labels or UITextFields as children, each with their own separate property.

By the way, the `rawChildren` property is only available on containers. It exists so that you can add "chrome" to a container that isn't part of the container's child layout algorithm. For example, Panel has a title bar and a border that aren't affected by the vertical/horizontal/absolute layout options.

Comment: Thank you very much for this in depth answer!

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a custom component that contains both labels as its children, instead of trying to throw a child on the Label?  That feels cleaner to me, as adding children to build-in components like that doesn't seem right.

Comment: I thought about this, but I like how a Label's size is auto to its own text, not sure how I could make a Canvas like that? Is there a way?

Comment: Sure, just set the size of your Canvas to the size of the Label.  There's a callback you need to override when defining your component in order to set the size at the right time, but I can't remember which method it is off the top of my head.  The Flex docs should be able to tell you.